# Create content for iframe of other domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

For our thesis we need to develop a prototype of the AdJail approach which provides security against malicious ads. The approach isolates advertisement scripts by placing them in a 'shadowpage' in an iframe with different origin. (protected by same origin policy) By copying the content of the original page to the shadowpage, the adscript has only access to the content the publisher has allowed access for.

The problem lies in creating the iframe for the shadowpage. 
Originally, we implemented this:

```
if (document.createElement && (iframe = document.createElement('iframe'))) {
        iframe.id = "shadowpage";
        iframe.name = "shadowpage";
        iframe.height = 1400; 
        iframe.width = 1400;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        var shadowScript = document.createElement("script");
        shadowScript.src = "ShadowTunnelScript.js";
        iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(shadowScript);
        adUrl = adScript;
}
```

Obviously, this does not provide the request security of the same origin policy since this iframe has the same origin as the containing page.

Our alternative is as follows with the src of the iframe set to a page with a different origin:

```
if (document.createElement && (iframe = document.createElement('iframe'))) {
        iframe.id = "shadowpage";
        iframe.name = "shadowpage";
        iframe.height = 1400; 
        iframe.width = 1400;
        iframe.src = "http://***/AdJail/Shadowpage.html";
        //iframe.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

But in this case, the user of our prototype needs to create a shadowpage himself on a different server.

Our question is: is it possible to create such an iframe with a different origin, generate dynamically the content of this iframe so that the user only needs to call a library without providing the shadowpage himself.

Is this perhaps possible by first generating the content of the iframe and then changing somehow the origin of the iframe?

Comment: HTML5 has "sandbox" attribute on iframe. But I guess browser support will take time to catch up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set a value to document.domain or set iframe contents as a datauri :

```
var content=window.btoa('<html>(..)<script>document.domain='sandbox';</script></html>');
iframe.src = "data:text/html;base64,"+content;
```